# Date format: Converting month/day/year to year-month-day format

Tags: mysql, date

I read "convert date string to mysql datetime field": but this did not help me

So what I am trying to do is read in a `dat file` into an empty table in `mysql`.

```
table CLIMBED(TRIP_ID int,PEAK VARCHAR(30),D_WHEN DATE);
```

The issue is the `.dat file` has the dates as follows:

```
1,'Lonely Mountain',06/11/2002
1,'Mount Everest',06/12/2002
1,'Mount Doom',06/13/2002
1,'Muah Mountain',06/14/2002
1,'Thor Peak',06/15/2002
```

And, when I load the data into the table it is inserted as: `0000-00-00`

How do I read in the file's date column as year-month-day?

I am learning sql any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: maybe change date format in application side before processing

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_FORMAT()` like:

Syntax:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date,format)
```

Try this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(D_WHEN DATE,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

For more reference [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Comment: Would this go in table declaration? create table CLIMBED(TRIP_ID int, PEAK VARCHAR(30), D_WHEN DATE); ? Or in the loading stage?

Comment: So I formatted the file to year-month-day in python. To read the file from the directory into mysql I am using the following command:                 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/Daniel/Documents/data/formatted.txt' into table CLIMBED COLUMNS terminated by ','  optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 lines;                                                      Now I get only some 0000-00-00 's       I get the following error: 1 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column 'D_WHEN' at row 156